# how to increase loading image time

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using p:dialog to restrict user while background process is running,
but as soon as ajax is completed dialog disappear, but my query is still going on and getting waiting for localhost.
I want to show dialog till the end of all process

```
<p:dialog styleClass="confirm" modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Loading..."
                draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" width="100"
                height="50">
                <div align="center">
                 <p:graphicImage value="../images/loading.gif" width="50"
                    height="50" />
                </div>
</p:dialog>
```

using it like

```
<p:commandLink action="#{roundingBean.ClearBean()}" value="#{msg['header.label.RoundingRuleManagement']}" onstart="statusDialog.show();" oncomplete="statusDialog.hide();" />
```

bean method

```
public String ClearBean(){

    countryCode=null;
    roundingModeId=null;
    roundingRuleName=null;
    description=null;
    roundingConstantIncrement=null;
    roundingRuleList=null;
    roundingModeDTOList=null;


    return WebConstants.REDIRECT_ROUNDING_VIEW_PAGE;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post your Backing Bean, because I tried your code and it works.

Comment: If you execute an async method on your server side you can use primefaces Ajax Poll to tell when to hide your dialog (instead of using `oncomplete` of your `p:commandLink `)